# How to insert multiple values from form, including multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

there!

I have this HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="incluindo1.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Incluir Produto</legend>
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="nome" class="" placeholder="Digite o nome"><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="" placeholder="Digite o email"><br>
            <label for="categoria">Categoria:</label><br>
            <select name="categoria">
                <option value="selecione">Selecione</option>
                <option value="a">A</option>
                <option value="b">B</option>
                <option value="c">C</option>
                <option value="d">D</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="preferencias">Preferências musicais:<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="preferencias[]" value="Clássica">Clássica
                <input type="checkbox" name="preferencias[]" value="Rock">Rock
                <input type="checkbox" name="preferencias[]" value="Pop">Pop
                <input type="checkbox" name="preferencias[]" value="MPB">MPB
                <input type="checkbox" name="preferencias[]" value="Flashouse">Flashouse
            </label><br>
            <textarea name="observacao" class="" placeholder="Digite sua observação"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Incluir" name="incluir" id="incluir">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And I have this PHP:

```
include "conecta_mysqli.inc.php";

$nome=$_POST["nome"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$categoria=$_POST["categoria"];
$preferencias=$_POST["preferencias"];
$observacao=$_POST["observacao"];

$inclusao = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO pessoas_a VALUES(null,'$nome','$email','$categoria','$preferencias','$observacao')");
```

And this SQL:

```
create table pessoas_a(
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(30) not null,
categoria char(1) not null,
preferencias text not null,
observacao text not null,
primary key(id)
);
```

How is the best way to insert those values in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

if your very simple form is alll you want/do

you can iterate over the `$preferencias as $preferencia` (because its an array)
and insert each entry in a query (use `$preferencia` instead, leave the rest), but that writes for each entry a row in the database, but you can also just `implode(',',$_POST["preferencias"])` too only write one entry (if that can implemented this way). depends all on what you want to do/try

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize your data if they are going to remain in the same row. The downside is, you won't be able to index and query those values. If not, you should build a separate table and cross reference the data. Below is the serializing approach.

```
include "conecta_mysqli.inc.php";
$nome=$_POST["nome"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$categoria=$_POST["categoria"];
$preferencias= serialize($_POST["preferencias"]);
$observacao= serialize($_POST["observacao"]);

$inclusao = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO pessoas_a VALUES(null,'$nome','$email','$categoria','$preferencias','$observacao')");
```